# Why use HashDict over Dict?

Tags: elixir

Elixir newbie here.  This question will be short and sweet!

I am learning Elixir through doing online programming exercises and was given the following advice about a recent submission:

> In general it's better to use Dict.foo instead of HashDict.foo if
>   possible. Dict functions work with all kinds of dictionaries so if
>   your code changes you'll have less places to update.

Which made me realise that I have no idea when you *should* use HashDict over Dict.  What special virtues does one have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HashDict's API matches Dict's API, because HashDict implements Dict.Behaviour. The recommendation to use Dict's API over HashDict's is because in general it's always a good idea to code against the interface instead of the implementation, where Dict in this case is the interface, and HashDict is an implementation of that interface.

I'm also not sure about Sasa's point regarding performance, it's possible that's a concern, but I'm almost 100% sure that in general you should be more concerned about *how* you are using a Dict, instead of how you are accessing it.

Comment: Good answer! HashDict is a concrete implementation of the Dict.Behaviour. It is more likely that a loss in performance will occur from which concrete implementation you are using, not any module lookup in the function dispatch. Using Dict, you can change which implementation you are using without having to change any of your access code.

Answer (score 3):

The only use case I can think of is performance optimization. `Dict` functions need to resolve the target module in run-time, and then forward the call to that module. Calling `HashDict` directly overcomes this step.

Im sure that in vast majority of situations this difference won't matter. But if you have a case where every microsecond counts, and you perform frequent calls to Dict, you might gain some speed by calling `HashDict` directly. Personally, I'd measure before doing this.

So long story short, `Dict` should serve you in 99,9999999% of cases :-)

Comment: Very interesting.  For some reason the HashDict concept was heavily pushed in an early exercise, so I kind of rolled with that.  It sounds like I should probably have always have been using Dict instead (at least until I can find an actual reason not to be!)

Comment: Maybe HashDict was used in exercise to avoid newcomer's confusion that might happen when HashDict.new is used to create a dict, but Dict is used to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, now you should just use `Map`.  [Dict is deprecated](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/Dict.html) as is [HashDict](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/HashDict.html)